# Python can't import module named wsgi_soap from the soaplib

Tags: python, soap

This code works on Debian under Python 2.5 but doesn't on Ubuntu under Python 2.6:

```
from soaplib.wsgi_soap import SimpleWSGISoapApp
```

On ubuntu under python 2.6 I get the error:

> > from soaplib.wsgi_soap import SimpleWSGISoapApp
> >
> > ImportError: No module named wsgi_soap

Comment: I have installed soaplib using easy_install.
After it didn't work I tried to install it using apt. The result was the same.

Comment: What's on your `PYTHONPATH`?  What's in `sys.path`?  What's in your library's `site-packages`?  The code -- obviously -- is fine.  It's your installation that's bad.  So provide more information about the installation.

Comment: ['', '/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/soaplib-0.9.1_alpha6-py2.6.egg', '/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/PyYAML-3.09-py2.6-linux-i686.egg', '/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/lxml-2.2.7-py2.6-linux-i686.egg', '/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/CherryPy-3.1.2-py2.6.egg', '/usr/lib/python2.6', '/usr/lib/python2.6/plat-linux2', '/usr/lib/python2.6/lib-tk', '/usr/lib/python2.6/lib-old', '/usr/lib/python2.6/lib-dynload', '/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6', '/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages']

Comment: "import soaplib"


works fine

Comment: @Roman Prikhodchenko: It seems to find `soaplib` ... what it doesn't find is `wsgi_soap` inside `soaplib` . Please try this code:  `import soaplib ; print soaplib`  and paste the result for us.

Comment: <module 'soaplib' from '/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/soaplib-0.9.1_alpha6-py2.6.egg/soaplib/__init__.pyc'>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used the latest version of the soaplib which is incompatible with the version 0.8.

Answer (score 2):

Don't call your own file `soaplib.py`. Rename it to something else. Also, remove the `soaplib.pyc` file that was generated.

Comment: If that answer is not correct, please provide full traceback of the error (not just a snippet as you did), and a listing of your `/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages` and `/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages` directory contents.

Comment: I don't call the file soaplib.py. The problem is python can't find one module of the library. However it can find other modules.

Comment: @Roman Prikhodchenko: It seems to find `soaplib` ... what it doesn't find is `wsgi_soap` inside `soaplib` . Please try this code:  `import soaplib ; print soaplib`  and paste the result for us.

Comment: <module 'soaplib' from '/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/soaplib-0.9.1_alpha6-py2.6.egg/soaplib/__init__.pyc'>

Comment: Heh - this just happened to me, but with pysvg - I decided to call my first test file 'pysvg.py', and kept getting `ImportError` :) Just renamed it and the error was gone :) +1, thanks !!